# MediaPlayer setDataSource failed with status=0x80000000 for Ringtone set by filepath on 2.3.4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, ringtone

Title says most of it.

My application has been playing ringtones pointed by uri like `content://media/internal/audio/media/387` or `content://media/external/audio/media/1655` (for custom ringtones on SDcard I believe) using both `setDataSource(fileInfo)` and `setDataSource(mContext, Uri.parse(fileInfo))`.

In each case I have received logs with information about `setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000` exception on phones using Android 4.x (different versions).

Seeing that the error happens only to ringtones pointed by content uri, but not to single files pointed by path, I have decided to use paths for ringtones as well which fixed problem on above phones (while still using `setDataSource(mContext, Uri.parse(fileInfo))` )

It has however started problems on phones with Android 2.3.4-2.3.6 (not on mine 2.3.3 though):

- I have received few logs with exception: `setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000` for files with paths like `/system/media/audio/ringtones/TwirlAway.ogg`
- I have also received a log about `MediaPlayer.onErrorListener.onError(int what, int extra)` method call with `what=1` and `extra=-2147483648`, which, from what I know, suggest either that file is missing or it is corrupted. However I perform

  ```
  File file = new File(fileInfo);
  if (!file.exists())
  ```

check in such situation and it returned that file does exist - is it corrupted then? Highly unlikely for music file in internal memory.

To sum up:

- works with `setDataSource("content://media/internal/audio/media/52")`
- throws exception: `setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000` for `setDataSource(mContext, "/system/media/audio/ringtones/TwirlAway.ogg")`

Interestingly, first few lines of `setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri, Headers headers)` method which is called by `setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)` are ([from GrepCode source for 2.3.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java)):

```
 String scheme = uri.getScheme();
     if(scheme == null || scheme.equals("file")) {
         setDataSource(uri.getPath());
         return;
     }
```

So, after all, it just fails for `setDataSource("/system/media/audio/ringtones/TwirlAway.ogg")`. I have taken paths to ringtones from uris by using:

```
private static String getRingtonePathFromContentUri(Context context,
        Uri contentUri) {

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    Cursor ringtoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            proj, null, null, null);
    ringtoneCursor.moveToFirst();
    return ringtoneCursor.getString(ringtoneCursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
}
```

Any ideas what can be causing error throwing? Maybe those are some issues caused by lack of reading permissions?
I guess source code for native setDataSource(String path) function would help a lot, but I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer by Lorne below was most helpful when dealing with this problem.

For anyone else struggling with it, here is the code that I have been using for over 6 months now with errors almost not reported anymore.

`fileinfo` can be both of below (examples):

`/system/media/audio/alarms/Walk_in_the_forest.ogg`

`content://media/internal/audio/media/20`

```
public static void setMediaPlayerDataSource(Context context,
        MediaPlayer mp, String fileInfo) throws Exception {

    if (fileInfo.startsWith("content://")) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileInfo);
            fileInfo = getRingtonePathFromContentUri(context, uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            try {
                setMediaPlayerDataSourcePreHoneyComb(context, mp, fileInfo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                setMediaPlayerDataSourcePostHoneyComb(context, mp, fileInfo);
            }
        else
            setMediaPlayerDataSourcePostHoneyComb(context, mp, fileInfo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            setMediaPlayerDataSourceUsingFileDescriptor(context, mp,
                    fileInfo);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            String uri = getRingtoneUriFromPath(context, fileInfo);
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(uri);
        }
    }
}

private static void setMediaPlayerDataSourcePreHoneyComb(Context context,
        MediaPlayer mp, String fileInfo) throws Exception {
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(fileInfo);
}

private static void setMediaPlayerDataSourcePostHoneyComb(Context context,
        MediaPlayer mp, String fileInfo) throws Exception {
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(Uri.encode(fileInfo)));
}

private static void setMediaPlayerDataSourceUsingFileDescriptor(
        Context context, MediaPlayer mp, String fileInfo) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(fileInfo);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
    inputStream.close();
}

private static String getRingtoneUriFromPath(Context context, String path) {
    Uri ringtonesUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(path);
    Cursor ringtoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ringtonesUri, null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "='" + path + "'", null, null);
    ringtoneCursor.moveToFirst();

    long id = ringtoneCursor.getLong(ringtoneCursor
            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
    ringtoneCursor.close();

    if (!ringtonesUri.toString().endsWith(String.valueOf(id))) {
        return ringtonesUri + "/" + id;
    }
    return ringtonesUri.toString();
}

public static String getRingtonePathFromContentUri(Context context,
        Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    Cursor ringtoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            proj, null, null, null);
    ringtoneCursor.moveToFirst();

    String path = ringtoneCursor.getString(ringtoneCursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

    ringtoneCursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to solve this problem for almost a month. Our app is even an **alarm app**, which should play the music or ringtone perfectly in the morning but until now there are so many crashes when playing the music.

Comment: I've been frustrated because of this problem and you saved my **month**!

Comment: how to work with path such as /storage/emulated/0/IDM/Music/xxx.mp3 ?? Even this is failing on this.

Comment: @jeevs what seems to be a problem? Above solution is still working for me. Maybe your file is corrupted or not found at this location?

Comment: This code won't work when your file path has spaces in it which are represented by %20 (e.g. file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/Artist%20(feat.%20ArtistPart1%20ArtistPart2).mp3), as the uri encode will replace %20 with spaces but afterwards the setDataSource won't work. If I simply remove the Uri.encode it works, but at what cost? I haven't seen a situation where the code without the encode part doesn't work but my test cases are limited.

Comment: @jeevs can you share your fix?

Comment: @MikeHoller I don't remember solution exactly and I don't have access to the source now. The solution was a fallback kind of solution first try the URI if it doesn't give a valid file descriptor then use the projection. However, the above code does work as Koger said, play around with it, you will get the solution working.

Comment: Best answer so far! Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 6):

You have to explicit set the length of your file. Use the overloaded method:
`AssetFileDescriptor afd = ctx.getAssets().openFd([your asset name]);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());`

Comment: Thank you, never thought this was causing the error! I used to call the overloaded method above but this time I called the simpler one without thinking..

Answer (score 4):

There was a change in the behaviour of `setDataSource(String path)` due to a bug fix in Android 4.1.1. In 4.1.1 or later you need to use a local path (without protocol). However, on 4.0.4 and earlier you needed to use a URI (e.g. with file:// protocol).

Here is an incomplete code snippet that should illustrate the workaround:

```
// as of 4.1.1 (JELLY_BEAN) we need to use a local path (without protocol)
// on 4.0.4 and earlier we needed a URI (with file:// protocol)
final String cachedFile = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 // android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
                        ? getCacheFilePath(file)
                        : getCacheFileUri(file);


// for the purpose of this example 
// assume cacheFolder is a String and getCacheFile returns a String

public String getCacheFilePath(String file) {
    return cacheFolder + getCacheFile(file);
}

public String getCacheFileUri(String file) {
    return "file://" + cacheFolder + getCacheFile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be happening because of file format you are trying to play or compress. I was compressing a mp4 file which works well but when I compress a mov file the application crashed giving the setDataSource failed exception.

Comment: That's true. It has mainly to do with file formats. Working with video files, I figure that out of the following video formats: AVI, MPG/MPEG, MOV, mov, mp4, m4v, flv, WMV, I noticed that AVI, MPG/MPEG, and WMV threw an exception for me every time. Better to exclude them before running the method and wrap it with a try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when I was trying to play a .wav file. Let´s make an example:

```
 private void start_player(){
// create raw folder inside the res folder if not present
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.your_wave_audio_file);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
               // Your Stuff
            }
        });  
         mPlayer.start();
     }
    }
```

I too got the status=0x80000000 error. In my case the solution was to re-encode the audio file (for example to 16-BIT PCM for a .wav file) and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.your_wave_audio_file);
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

You can't do it, because prepare was called in create function, therefore you can't change Audio Stream Type after.

Below code is worked fine for me:

```
sMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
sMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getResources().
         openRawResourceFd(R.raw.cool_song);

 if(assetFileDescriptor == null) return;

 try {
    sMediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                               assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), 
                               assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
    assetFileDescriptor.close();

    sMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(sMediaPlayer != null){
                sMediaPlayer.release();
                sMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    });

    sMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {               
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            sMediaPlayer.start();                   
        }
    });
    sMediaPlayer.prepare();

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    HelpFunctions.showLog("ERROR = " + e);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    HelpFunctions.showLog("ERROR = " + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    HelpFunctions.showLog("ERROR = " + e);
}
```