# How to get the absolute path of a file?

Tags: android

I want to get the absolute path of a file which is selected from a file chooser.
My `OnActivityesult()` is like below:

```
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case 1:
                Uri pathUri = data.getData();
                File userFile = new File(pathUri.getPath());
                IMG_PATH = userFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
                Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), IMG_PATH, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ShowConfirmation(IMG_PATH);
                break;
        }
    }
```

but this code returns like `/document/primary:miniclipId.txt`.
I need the real path like `mnt/sdcard1/miniclipId.txt`.
The user will choose `.img` file from sdcard or internal.
Can anybody tell me how can i get the path string like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get filepath from google drive in Lollipop (MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA == null)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378651/get-filepath-from-google-drive-in-lollipop-mediastore-mediacolumns-data-null)

Comment: This code is for choosing `.img` file from sdcard, not media files

Comment: The source of file is irrelevant. I recommend you to read the answer to linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but this code returen like /document/primary:miniclipId.txt.

You received a `Uri` from a `ContentProvider`.

> I need the real path like mnt/sdcard1/miniclipId.txt.

A `Uri` is not a file. There is no requirement that there be a "real path", let alone one that is meaningful to you.

Use `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to [consume the content pointed to by the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

If you absolutely need a file, use `openInputStream()` and copy the content to some file that you control.

Comment: If there are relative paths in the file to other files and I need to use them within cross-compiled libraries. Is there a clever way to do that?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn: If by "in the file", you mean "in the content identified by the `Uri`", then there is no reliable way to handle what you are seeking.

Comment: Is there a (reliable?) way to handle the subset of cases where the content identified by the `Uri` is a local file?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn: If you only want to work with local files, stop using things involving `Uri` values. Instead, [use a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). This will limit you to files that you can access via the filesystem, and then normal filesystem traversal rules apply for things like relative paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds like the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

u can use this function to get real path of media.u just have to pass uri that u get in onActivityResult() method

```
 public String mf_szGetRealPathFromURI(final Uri ac_Uri) {
    String result = "";
    boolean isok = false;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ac_Uri, proj,
                null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        isok = true;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return isok ? result : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using for years

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri, Context activity) {
    String path = null;
    try {
        final String[] proj = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        final Cursor cursor = ((Activity) activity).managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (path != null && path.length() > 0) {
        return path;
    } else return contentUri.getPath();
}
```