# Is it a bug in MediaPlayer in 4.4.2 and 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play mp3 sound some times like count numbers. When I use this code in 6.0.1 it works but in 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 the app crashed do not know why? 
Is there any way to solve it or is there any sound libs to play mp3.

**note**: I tried Vitamio for playing sound but it has a bug.

```
   media = MediaPlayer.create(this, com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.R.raw.sound_count);

    media.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                                media.start();
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(50);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**
This is the Logcat

```
    12-01 14:30:32.315 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/View: Touch down dispatch to com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.TextViewStyle{425ec3c0 V.ED..C. ......I. 0,11-232,55 #7f0e01c4 app:id/player_vs_device}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=161.9512, y[0]=27.956726, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2426605, downTime=2426605, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
12-01 14:30:32.328 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x54c9c8e8) (w:384, h:380, f:1)
12-01 14:30:32.432 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/View: Touch up dispatch to com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.TextViewStyle{425ec3c0 V.ED..C. ...P.... 0,11-232,55 #7f0e01c4 app:id/player_vs_device}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=161.9512, y[0]=27.956726, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2426718, downTime=2426605, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
12-01 14:30:32.450 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk V/Provider/Settings: get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
12-01 14:30:32.450 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk V/Provider/Settings:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
12-01 14:30:32.502 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: Don't notify duration to com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk!
12-01 14:30:32.547 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x54c8b810) (w:384, h:380, f:1)
12-01 14:30:32.550 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-01 14:30:32.551 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x54ca1a80) (w:384 h:380 f:1)
12-01 14:30:32.552 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x54c9c8e8) (w:384 h:380 f:1)
12-01 14:30:32.552 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x54c8b810) (w:384 h:380 f:1)
12-01 14:30:32.579 15197-15535/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: interp stack at 0x54cab000
12-01 14:30:32.579 15197-15535/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: adding to list (attached)
12-01 14:30:32.579 15197-15535/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=11: attached from native, name=Binder_3
12-01 14:30:32.641 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(5, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:32.641 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(1, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:32.642 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-01 14:30:32.642 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(6, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:32.658 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#1810580
12-01 14:30:32.669 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{425fc3f8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-600,973} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41e13c88 controlFlags=#100
12-01 14:30:33.010 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: Don't notify duration to com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk!
12-01 14:30:33.047 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{425f9010 token=android.os.BinderProxy@425f86e0 {com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.MainActivity}}
12-01 14:30:33.066 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@425f86e0
12-01 14:30:33.070 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-01 14:30:33.105 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(2, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:33.108 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(7, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:33.108 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(5, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:33.108 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(1, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:33.109 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-01 14:30:33.109 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(6, 0, 0)
12-01 14:30:33.128 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity.finishAfterTransition, referenced from method com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity.onBackPressed
12-01 14:30:33.128 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21941: Lcom/alkhulaqi/abdalrhman/htkxhtk/StageActivity;.finishAfterTransition ()V
12-01 14:30:33.128 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
12-01 14:30:33.151 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{41e16568 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41e15c38 {com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@41cec608, appName=com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk, pkg=com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk, comp={com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk-2.apk
12-01 14:30:33.161 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-01 14:30:33.161 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-01 14:30:33.162 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20178: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-01 14:30:33.162 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-01 14:30:33.162 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-01 14:30:33.162 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20182: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-01 14:30:33.162 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-01 14:30:33.203 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, config 6, w 247, h 400, sample 1, bsLength 25be!!
12-01 14:30:33.208 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/skia: jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1881!!!
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: SuspendAll starting
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=11 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=10 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=9 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=8 status=2 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=7 status=4 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=6 status=4 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=5 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=4 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=3 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1:   threadid=2 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
12-01 14:30:33.210 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: SuspendAll complete : 1
12-01 14:30:33.254 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: ResumeAll starting
12-01 14:30:33.254 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: ResumeAll waking others
12-01 14:30:33.254 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: ResumeAll complete
12-01 14:30:33.255 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 974K (21314), 25% free 11259K/14960K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
12-01 14:30:33.268 15197-15207/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
12-01 14:30:33.282 15197-15207/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
12-01 14:30:33.349 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-01 14:30:33.350 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 661: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-01 14:30:33.350 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-01 14:30:33.351 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-01 14:30:33.351 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 683: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-01 14:30:33.352 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-01 14:30:33.453 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
12-01 14:30:33.474 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
                                                                               java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
                                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1035)
                                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:855)
                                                                                   at com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity.onCreate(StageActivity.java:93)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 14:30:33.478 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-01 14:30:33.478 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: detach (group=0x41860ce0)
12-01 14:30:33.478 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41860ce0)
12-01 14:30:33.478 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
12-01 14:30:33.480 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 14:30:33.481 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
12-01 14:30:33.482 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:30:33.483 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 14:30:33.483 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
12-01 14:30:33.483 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
12-01 14:30:33.484 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 14:30:33.485 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 14:30:33.489 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity.onCreate(StageActivity.java:94)
12-01 14:30:33.490 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
12-01 14:30:33.490 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
12-01 14:30:33.490 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
12-01 14:30:33.490 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/System.err:   ... 11 more
12-01 14:30:33.490 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
12-01 14:30:33.494 15197-15197/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk, PID: 15197
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk/com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at com.alkhulaqi.abdalrhman.htkxhtk.StageActivity.onCreate(StageActivity.java:94)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the crash report

Comment: I update it. Logcat is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception you are getting is `java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000`

You generally get this exception if the file is corrupted , check with some other files if getting same exception.

Also check out these

**>** [MediaPlayer setDataSource failed with status=0x80000000 for Ringtone set by filepath on 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395559/mediaplayer-setdatasource-failed-with-status-0x80000000-for-ringtone-set-by-file)

and

**>** [MediaPlayer.setDataSource causes IOException for valid file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657280/mediaplayer-setdatasource-causes-ioexception-for-valid-file)

Comment: Yes the mp3 file has some encode so mediaplayer can not play it. Link 2 helps me. Thank you man;)

Comment: But it just play it for once. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

For playing media(mp3) use below code. it is supported in every android api level.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_count); 


                try
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            mediaPlayer.reset(); // This is for when you need to make null mediaplayer.
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioPath);  //This is for when you play audio from your phone memory.
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Still if you have an query or error then let me know.
Thank you.