# How to convert a string to uri without language error?

Tags: java, android, file, uri

I have a `Mediametadatareview`, but when I use `setDataSource()` gets out, I notice the error is due to a file with the name `/storage/sdcard/NhạcCuảTôi.mp3` (The file name is Vietnamese). How to change that file to a true URI?

this is my code

```
 mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();       
 Uri u = Uri.parse(filedata);
 mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MainAC.this, u);
 String gene= mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
```

it crashed at  `mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MainAC.this, u);`

I think the error is because the file name has an accent, is there any way to help convert the string to URI and unmark?
Because if I delete the file with that sign then the application works normally

this is LOGCAT :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dragonrocky.music/dragonrocky.music.MainAC}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:71)
    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:165)
    at dragonrocky.music.MainAC.loadAudio(MainAC.java:519)
    at dragonrocky.music.MainAC.onCreate(MainAC.java:156)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
```

Thank You.

Comment: add the error logcat and the code snippet please

Comment: I corrected my post, can you help me ,thank you.

Comment: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395559/mediaplayer-setdatasource-failed-with-status-0x80000000-for-ringtone-set-by-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("/storage/sdcard/NhạcCuảTôi.mp3");
```

Comment: but it will application has been stop

Comment: Looks like your media file is corrupt, can you check the file using some desktop app  or some other media player

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `Uri` here. Either use the `setDataSource(String)` method and pass your path in directly, or open the file yourself and use `setDataSource(FileDescriptor)`.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: ok, i left LOGCAT above the post and i realized the problem is not in the filename because the previous filename also has the accent and it works normal